# How to configure Serilog to use a log4net sink?

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, serilog

Until now I was using a log4net logger that was configured on start of the application:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogRoot"] = @"../logs";
var log4netConfigFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\log4net.config";
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(log4netConfigFile));
```

The code above ensured the log to be written in ../logs folder using configuration file log4net.config

Now I am beginning using Serilog and would like to keep the current log4net logging, but controlled from Serilog that has a dedicated log4net sink. So I kept the code above and wrote the following additional code:

```
var logger = new Serilog.LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
    .WriteTo.Log4Net()
    .CreateLogger();
```

I see that the log file is created on application startup, but no longer are written as long as I am using Serilog logger.

Shouldn't Serilog use log4net configuration with its log4net sink?

Comment: This looks like it might be a bug; setting `SelfLog.Out = Console.Error` should reveal any exceptions thrown...

Comment: No, it didn't reveal any errors when added this code line.

Comment: We've fixed a bug in 1.3.35 that is likely to be the source of this issue, upgrading should resolve it. https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/145

Comment: No it didn't help. I have written a small app to reproduce the issue. Will post it now.

Comment: Here's the gist that reproduces the problem: https://gist.github.com/object/a7139800bd8e9fa8358c

Comment: Sorry it did help! I just used wrong logging level, after I changed it everything worked.